# personal cloud storage and microsoft teams

Tags: synchronization, cloud, microsoft-teams, seafile-server

I am using Microsoft teams to share my files with my colleagues. I also have a personal could storage based on the Seafile application.
I would like to find a way to synchronize my files on Microsoft teams and my folder using my personal cloud.
Is it possible to do it without using a predefined cloud storage proposed by Microsoft teams (one drive, dropbox, google drive ...) and without creating an account on my server for my colleagues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. Teams have predefined cloud storage which is supported.
[image]